# "sudo -u www-data git pull" Credential Saving?

Tags: php, git, ubuntu, apache2

I have my apache2 webserver directory as a Git directory, so when me and my team members (school project) make changes to our GitHub folder, it can easily be pulled by running '`git pull`' in putty.

I want to make this automatic (using a WebHook) by having a "`pull.php`" file that has "`<?php exec("git pull"); <?`" inside it.

However, the user that shows up when I run `whoami` function in php is "`www-data`".
In order to allow `www-data` to run `git pull` without having to enter credentials (I tried setting up SSH and it refused to work), I need to allow them to store credentials.

This is problematic because unlike other users, `www-data` has no directory in `/home/accountname` to save its `.gitconfig` to.

How do I go about having "`git credential.helper store`" work for `www-data`?

I would also not mind having SSH, but I run into the same problem where the default directory to save the `id_rsa` file to says no permission/does not exist, so I would prefer the previous question to be answered.

EDIT: In the end it was a variety of problems. it was trying to pull using HTTPS because i cloned it using HTTPS. long story short, i ended up deleting the repo and recloning it with SSH and all of my problems went away. There were a lot of steps in between but anyone with a similar problem can just do that and skip the headache haha.

Comment: Is it possible to pull the git repo by https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a similar issue in [`WordOps/WordOps` #305](https://github.com/WordOps/WordOps/issues/305)

> www-data user cannot write anything in `/var/www` because this directory's owner is `root`.
> So you can create the `.gitconfig` file as root, and then change owner and permissions (following [this recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/a/750516/5470)) with
>
> ```
> chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.gitconfig
> chmod 644 /var/www/.gitconfig.
> ```
>
> Or you can change `/var/www` directory owner (`chown www-data /var/www`) to allow `www-data` to create files in this directory.

The [OP ChristianWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17939188/christianwagner) confirms that cloning the repository with SSH instead of HTTPS allows for the `git pull` to work.

Comment: After doing this and running "sudo -u www-data git config credential.helper store
" and then trying to "sudo -u www-data git pull" and filling in the credentials i am met with this : fatal: unable to get credential storage lock: Permission denied
so im unsure how to fix that- i ran into this problem earlier and tried deleting a bunch of stuff like it said online and nothing worked.

Comment: Ah, your second comment was the fix! I needed to make www-data the directory owner to have permissions for the storage file for the credentials to be made. You just helped me solve something ive been having trouble with for like 7 hours, thank you haha! (also thank you for fixing my post, it looks beautiful now instead of the mess it was before)

Comment: ... sorry to bother you again, but after getting this all working im still having trouble getting my php to auto "git pull"... my webhook is directed at https://www.mydomain.xyz/pull.php and my pull.php contains "exec("sh -c cd /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/351Project && git pull");" i also tried just "git pull" etc and none work. The directory is owned by www-data and "echo exec('whoami');" returns www-data. Doing "sudo -u git pull" works perfectly in putty, but i cannot get it to work via webhook and php. Can you shed some light on how to properly get this to work?

Comment: @ChristianWagner would a simple `id -a && ls` in your php file work? Just to check if simpler commands are working.

Comment: yes, when i put "echo exec("id -a && ls");" it returns "welcome.php" when i go to mydomain.com/pull.php which is a file in the same directory as pull.php, so some commands are being executed but i dont think thats right at all lol

Comment: this is what happens when i go into the directory and run the command given from command line [https://i.imgur.com/5Bbnu5t.png](https://i.imgur.com/5Bbnu5t.png) which is far different than the "welcome.php" return when the command is run from going to mydomain.com/pull.php ---> "welcome.php" || this is the information from "ls -l" [https://i.imgur.com/v8zNuPZ.png](https://i.imgur.com/v8zNuPZ.png) @VonC

Comment: @ChristianWagner Try for testing this php webhook handler: https://gist.github.com/slowkow/92f021272e760d10d111d7fb72679276

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243739/discussion-between-christianwagner-and-vonc).