# How to set a git username when working with 'www-data' user

Tags: php, git, docker

I'm working on [php-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/8.1.3-fpm/images/sha256-67ea2e24922983a4bb01cdd5208bcc4759bbaeeea409670e7303dff7602ebb46) Docker image.
I want to set a git username from the www-data user. I try with php code but with no success then I try this command :

```bash
su -c 'git config --global user.name "<my-user>"' -s /bin/sh www-data
```

This command give me the following error:

`error: could not lock config file /var/www/.gitconfig: Permission denied`

And I have already applied this command ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71793210/11259771)) :

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.gitconfig
chmod 644 /var/www/.gitconfig
```

Any solution ?

I try this command:

`su -c 'git config --global user.name "<my-user>"' -s /bin/sh www-data`

And, I got this error:

`error: could not lock config file /var/www/.gitconfig: Permission denied`

Result code is of this command :

```bash
echo $? 
255
```

I expect that the command pass with success

Comment: Just out of interest...why?

Comment: Do `cd /var && chown www-data:www-data www` and then `su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'git config --global user.name "Jonny Null"'`. It might be of value to give us a bit more context. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to commit code and push to a remote repo using www-data user?

Comment: Its better to create plain new user and new user group via docker file. Then either add user to `www-data` group or do vice versa and add www-data to newly created group. Then change permissions for `www/html` folder. And also don't forget about `chmod` for files in case if you accidently switch from one user to another in order to commit the changes. You can also set your user as owner in php-fpm `listen.owner = <username>`. its important to incapsulate as much as possible and do not use predefined users, group etc.

Comment: @ADyson, I have a web application where there is a section for the admin to set username and email. And this app will generate code, commit it and push it to git remote repo via SSH. This part for the admin to change the git user who will commit and push the code, hope this explains a bit.

Comment: @zedfoxus, thanks, `chown www-data:www-data www` do the trick.

Comment: @MohamedAyadi that's great! If you see a check mark by your answer, click it to mark your answer as accepted. That way, others with a similar problem can see that your question has been solved and are likely to learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @zedfoxus,

The issue is that the user `www-data` can't make operations on the folder `/var/www`

So this command solve the problem :

```bash
cd /var
chown www-data:www-data www
```